# Implementation of DCC-GARCH

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, runtime-error

I have some issues implementing the DCC-GARCH in R. When I run the following code in R, I always get the same error message that says:

> Error in UseMethod("convergence") : 
>     no applicable method for 'convergence' applied to an object of class "try-error"

Unfortunately I have no idea how to fix this...

```
    install.packages("fGarch")
    install.packages("rugarch")
    install.packages("rmgarch")
    library(fGarch)
    library(rmgarch)
    library(rugarch)
    library(tseries)
    library(zoo)

    #Daten runterladen
    ibm <- get.hist.quote(instrument = "DB",  start = "2005-11-21",
                  quote = "AdjClose")
    sys<- get.hist.quote(instrument = "^STOXX50E",  start = "2005-11-21",
                 quote = "AdjClose")

    #Returns
    retibm<-diff(log(ibm))
    retsys<-diff(log(sys))

    # univariate normal GARCH(1,1) for each series
    garch11.spec = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0)), 
                      variance.model = list(garchOrder = c(1,1), 
                                            model = "sGARCH"), 
                      distribution.model = "norm")

    # dcc specification - GARCH(1,1) for conditional correlations
    dcc.garch11.spec = dccspec(uspec = multispec( replicate(2, garch11.spec) ), 
                       dccOrder = c(1,1), 
                       distribution = "mvnorm")
    dcc.garch11.spec

    MSFT.GSPC.ret = merge(retsys,retibm)
    plot(MSFT.GSPC.ret)
    dcc.fit = dccfit(dcc.garch11.spec, data = MSFT.GSPC.ret)
```

I wasn't sure if this subforum was the right one, but it seemed more appropiate than the quantitative finance forum. If it is the wrong one, I apologize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is caused by a somewhat nonstandard behaviour of `merge`. When merging by column names, we have `all = FALSE` by default. However, when merging by row names, as in this case, it seems that we have `all = TRUE` and, hence, `MSFT.GSPC.ret` contains `NA` values.

So, using either

```
MSFT.GSPC.ret <- merge(retsys, retibm, all = FALSE)
```

or

```
dcc.fit <- dccfit(dcc.garch11.spec, data = na.omit(MSFT.GSPC.ret))
```

solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much!